# Executing long running binary which needs root

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, root

I'm new in Mac development.
I want to execute long running binary (I have compiled version only) file which needs root privileges but i want to do it without sudo, because app should meet Apple's policies.

I tried STPrivilegedTask but it stops execution after a while (I have called waitUntilExit method).
I've read Apple's documentation about running some task with privileges. But didn't understand the main thing how to run compiled binary. Tried the SMJobBless sample as well as EvenBetterAuthorizationSample.
People if you have any experience in execution task with privileges, please answer me.

Thanks in advance